# How connect to strangers via Freenet? (OSX)

Tags: freenet

I see list of strangers, but dunno how to connect to them.

Where can I find step by step information about this?

Answer (score 1):

In opennet mode, you do not need to do *anything* yourself – Freenet automatically obtains a list of peers from the supernodes, and keeps trying to connect to them. That's what the list shows.

Freenet is a *distributed storage* network, more like BitTorrent than DC++. In other words, you cannot just "connect to" someone and see all their shared files – only the opposite is possible; once you have the URL for a specific file, Freenet will automatically find where the pieces are stored.